# CMAC-AES on iOS

Tags: ios, cryptography, aes, cmac

I'm converting an Android app to iOS. The Android version uses CMAC-AES cryptography, but I couldn't find CMAC for iOS. Does anyone know a library or could give a tip? I am not familiar with cryptography, so I am little messy.

Answer (score 1):

CMAC stands for Cipher-based Message Authentication Code, that means it's a message authentication code (it is used to authenticate data and avoid any corruption of the data being authenticated) that uses ciphers to achieve its goals, in your particular case it uses the AES cipher to do so.

There are indeed some libraries that you could use, you may [use OpenSSL](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/09/21/openssl-for-ios-swift-the-easy-way/) (you may try others tutorials that links OpenSSL to your project) which is a well adopted library and heavily maintened.